# Meet-in-the-middle attack (different block cipher modes)

Tags: block-cipher, cbc, des, ecb, meet-in-the-middle-attack

Does a meet-in-the-middle attack on depend on the used modes for block ciphers?

**encryption:** $C_i$ = $D_{K2}$($D_{K1}$($E_{K1}$($P_i$ $\oplus$ $C''_{i-1}$))) $\oplus$ $C'_{i-1}$ and $IV_1$ = $C''_0$ = $O^n$

with $C'$ and $C''$ be the intermediate solutions (and $C''$ the first) of each encryption/decryption method.

**decryption:** $P_i$ = $D_{K1}$($E_{K1}$($E_{K2}$($C_i$ $\oplus$ $C'_{i-1}$)) $\oplus$ $P_{i-1}$)

All the steps are DES and the first encryption on the plaintext is in CBC mode then that is decrypted in ECB mode and finally CBC mode to generate the final cipher.

Does this change anything for the meet-in-the-middle attack?

Comment: You have D_{K1}(E_{K1}(.)) which must be a typo

Comment: @kodlu this was an exercice provided for an exam. It's on purpose so that the first iteration negates it. I assume this also makes it more vulnerable for meet-in-the-middle but would like a second opinion